# Jquery addClass not working after removing class

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a code for next slide button of a JQuery slider

```
function sliderNext() {
  var sliderItemsCount=$('#usersToolsSlider li').length;
  if($('.show').last().index()>=(sliderItemsCount-1)){
    $('#usersToolsSlider li:first').addClass('show');
  } else {
    $('.show').next('li').addClass('show');
  }
  $('.show').first().removeClass('show');}
```

After I remove class ،  this line

```
$('#usersToolsSlider li:first').addClass('show');
```

It does not work

Comment: It is presently unclear what your problem is. The line that you say removes a class actually adds on, not removes.

Comment: i forgot put  , to my text

Answer (score 0):

When you are moving from last element to first one, this line:

```
$('.show').first().removeClass('show');
```

is removing the 'show' class from the first element where you added before.

A cleaner and working version:

```
function sliderNext() {
    var sliderItemsCount = $('#usersToolsSlider li').length;
    var isLastElement = ($('.show').last().index()>=(sliderItemsCount-1));
    if (isLastElement) {
        nextVisibleElement = $('#usersToolsSlider li:first');
    } else {
        nextVisibleElement = $('.show').next('li');
    }

    $('.show').removeClass('show');
    nextVisibleElement.addClass('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's `.hide()`, `.show()`, and `.is(':visible')` instead. This will prevent the need from toggling classes on and off.

```
function sliderNext() {    
  //hide the current visible slider and keep it for comparison
  const previousVisible = $('#usersToolsSlider li:visible').hide();

  if(previousVisible[0] == $('#usersToolsSlider li:last')[0]) {
    //If the last slider was visible, show the first slider
    $('#usersToolsSlider li:first').show();
  } else {
    //Else show the next slider
    previousVisible.next().show();
  }
}
```

**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/nx8u5kqo/2/

Comment: Why are there 3 show()'s and the hide() is outside the function? Ó_ò

Comment: @raul.vila op's example

Comment: Should not this line:
$('.show').first().removeClass('show');

be replaced with ... hide() instead of ...show() ?

Comment: This still fails with the transition from last to first (as in OP code) because $('#usersToolsSlider li:first').show(); will show the first option and that first option will be hidden by $('#usersToolsSlider li:visible:first').hide();

Comment: I think the last line of code that the op is calling out is being called from somewhere else, but not possitive

Comment: Last line is just the line inside the (true part of the) "if" repeated, pointing what he thinks is not working. It's working but he is removing the added class at the end.

Comment: I think I understand the task better now... updated.

Comment: You need to add [0] to the elements of the if:
Not working version: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/h45hdo5g/ - Working version: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/h45hdo5g/2/